# Apache wicket Button setMarkupId not working

Tags: java, javascript, html, apache, wicket

I have:

- `ListView`
- `Button`
- `WebMarkupContainer` (Popup content container)

So, when I populate the `ListView`, I add an `AjaxEventBehavior` to the buttons. I also override `getAjaxCallDecorator()`, as I need to call a javascript function from each button. So, in the `decorateScript` function, I override the `WebMarkupContainer` markup id by using `setMarkupId()`, it works. I do the same for the `Button`, and it works, at least when I call `getMarkupId()`. But when I go to the generated HTML, it's not there! Why is this happening?

The code is the following (it is inside of the `populateItem` from `ListView`):

```
infoBtn.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    }

    @Override
    protected IAjaxCallDecorator getAjaxCallDecorator() {

        return new IAjaxCallDecorator() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence decorateScript(Component component, CharSequence script) {
                StringBuilder jsScript = new StringBuilder();                                                                                               

                infoPopoverContent.setMarkupId(infoPopoverContent.getMarkupId(true) + String.valueOf(pos));
                infoBtn.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
                infoBtn.setMarkupId(infoBtn.getMarkupId() + String.valueOf(pos));

                jsScript.append("$('#" + infoBtn.getMarkupId() + "').popover({");
                    jsScript.append("html:true,");
                    jsScript.append("placement:'bottom',");
                    jsScript.append("content:function() {");
                        jsScript.append("return $('#");
                        jsScript.append(infoPopoverContent.getMarkupId());
                        jsScript.append("').html();");
                    jsScript.append("}");
                jsScript.append("});");

                logger.debug(jsScript.toString());

                pos++;

                return jsScript;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence decorateOnSuccessScript(Component component,
                    CharSequence script) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence decorateOnFailureScript(Component component,
                    CharSequence script) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        }; 
    }
});
```

Comment: What you're trying to do, you can do it much easier in Wicket!

Comment: Talking about your problem: please, post piece of HTML markup that's used for populating items. Also, if it's possible, post the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling [`infoBtn.setOutputMarkupId(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupId%28boolean%29), so that Wicket knows it should be outputting the `id` attribute.

Notice [`setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag%28boolean%29) is also calling `setOutputMarkupId(true)` behind the scenes. Without knowing much about your code, it looks like you don't really need it. `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag()` will output an emtpy container (`<span id="xxx">` in case the component is not visible, just to have a reference to the place the component belgons to, and allowing Wicket for manipulation via DOM in the AJAX response (for example, to make the component visible again).

As a side note, if you don't really need the `id` attributes to have a specific value, you can simplify your code by not using `setMarkupId()` and letting Wicket generate `id`s for you.

Also, it might be simpler to drop the `IAjaxCallDecorator` and just append the script in `onEvent` by means of [`AjaxRequestTarget#appendJavascript()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#appendJavascript%28java.lang.String%29) or [`AjaxRequestTarget`#prependJavascript()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html#prependJavascript%28java.lang.String%29), depending on your needs.